# In Edit Mode, is it possible to invert selection?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, selection-tools

I wish to select areas of a mesh, but it would be much simpler to just select the ones I don't want selected (because they are easier to access), and then inverse the selection.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This can be done with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> or *Select -> Inverse*.

[image]

It detects which selection mode you're in, and inverts the selection by vertices, edges or faces appropriately.

[image]